# String slicing not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently doing a program for my Python class. The description is here:

Write a short python program, YI_swapOandE.py to replace an ‘o’ with an ‘e’. Prompt the user for a word and display the swapped version of it if it contains an o. Otherwise, the program will just display the original word. This program must use the slicing technique you learned in the Hangman program.
Example:
Type a word and I will replace any 'o' with an 'e': broom
The swapped word is: breem

So far, after she told us to re-use some code, I did this:

```
def splicing():
    word = input("Please input a word")
    for i in range(len(word)):
        letter = word[i]
        if letter == 'o':
            word = letter[:i] + word[i] + letter[i+1:]
    print(word)


def main():
    splicing()


main()
```

yeah i understand that some bits aren't perfect but i just need help with one bit.

Currently, I'm getting the error: string index out of range

how do I fix this?

Comment: `letter[:i] + word[i] + letter[i+1:]` looks like you're sticking a word in the middle of a letter, instead of the other way around.

Comment: `word = word[:i] + 'e' + word[i+1:]`

Comment: You get the price for today's least speaking question title ;-)

Comment: Echoing @Alfe : PLEASE change your title to contain at least SOME information (hopefully a lot). I downvoted your question because of this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `letter = word[i]`. I think you're confusing what it is.

You're going on to treat that like it's a string with multiple characters.

```
def splicing():
    word = input("Please input a word")
    for i in range(len(word)):
        letter = word[i]
        if letter == 'o':
            word = word[:i] + 'e' + word[i+1:]
    print(word)


def main():
    splicing()


main()
```

Comment: Hi @StephendeRiel if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
def splicing():
    word = input("Please input a word")
    for i in range(len(word)):
        letter = word[i]
        if letter == 'o':
            word = letter[:i] + word[i] + letter[i+1:]
    print(word)
```

let's see

```
        letter = word[i]
        if letter == 'o':
```

can be simplified to

```
        if word[i] == 'o':
```

now, let's examine what you do when you find an 'o'

```
            word = letter[:i] + word[i] + letter[i+1:]
```

using your previous use of `letter` you have

```
            word = word[i] + word[i] + word[i]
```

and it's not what you want, first of all because you do not put an 'e' in your word...

```
            word = word[:i]+'e'+word[1+1:]
```

Summing it up

```
def splicing():
    word = input("Please input a word")
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == 'o':
            word = word[:i]+'e'+word[i+1:]
    print(word)
```

The above procedure is appropriate at your current level, but it's not efficient because you're building the string that is known as `word` again and again... its much more efficient to convert the string to a data structure that can be changed in place, operate the substitution and convert back to a string

```
>>> word = 'Popeye & Olive'
>>> l = [c for c in word]
>>> print(l)
['P', 'o', 'p', 'e', 'y', 'e', ' ', '&', ' ', 'O', 'l', 'i', 'v', 'e']
```

Now you can apply the modification while building the new data structure:

```
>>> l = ['e' if c == 'o' else c for c in word]
>>> print(l)
['P', 'e', 'p', 'e', 'y', 'e', ' ', '&', ' ', 'O', 'l', 'i', 'v', 'e']
```

it is very readable, isn't it?

Now let'g go a step further and change also the capital 'O'

```
>>> l = ['e' if c == 'o' else 'E' if c == 'O' else c for c in word]
```

it's a bit more complex but still readable...

```
>>> print(l)
['P', 'e', 'p', 'e', 'y', 'e', ' ', '&', ' ', 'E', 'l', 'i', 'v', 'e']
```

but this is not what we want, we want a string!

For this purpose python provides the `str.join()` method --- here we want to join the elements of `l` using the null string `""`

```
>>> print("".join(l))
Pepeye & Elive
>>>
```

If we want to put it all together

```
>>> word = "".join(['e' if c=='o' else 'E' if c=='O' else c for c in word])
>>> print(word)
Pepeye & Elive
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` can do what you want to achieve:

```
>>> "hello how are you".replace('o','e')
'helle hew are yeu'
>>> "broom".replace('o','e')
'breem'
```

some modification to your code:

```
def splicing():      
    word = input("Please input a word")
    modify = ''
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == 'o':
            modify += 'e'
        else: modify += word[i]
    print(modify)

def main():
    splicing()

main()
```

Comment: The OP isn't looping over the string. for i in range(len(word)) is looping over a list of integers.

Comment: You're talking about modifying something you're looping over and that's just not happening in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `letter` to be a single character:

```
letter = word[i]
```

But then in this line:

```
word = letter[:i] + word[i] + letter[i+1:]
```

...you're slicing it. That's the cause of the error. Changing both of the references to `letter` in that line with `word` is probably what you're trying to do, but you'll also need to change the one reference to `word` that you already have in there. (Hint: since you're only hitting the inside of this block when you see an 'o', you know exactly what you want to go there. No variable needed.)